# Finding the modulus and argument of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

**My problem:**

> Find the magnitude and argument of the following.
>   $$\frac{3+4i}{1-i} + \frac{2-i}{2+3i}$$

---

**My solution so far:**

\begin{align}
\frac{3+4i}{1-i} + \frac{2-i}{2+3i} &= \frac{3+4i}{1-i} \times \frac{1+i}{1+i} + \frac{2-i}{2+3i} \times \frac{2-3i}{2-3i}\\
&=\frac{3+3i+4i+4(-1)}{1+1} + \frac{4-6i-2i+3(-1)}{4+9(-1)}\\
&= \frac{3+7i-4}{2} + \frac{4-8i-3}{13} \\
&= \frac{-1+7i}{2} + \frac{1-8i}{13}\\
&= \frac{-13+91i+2-16i}{26}
\end{align}

Thus the complex number is given by
$$ z = \frac{-11+75i}{26}=  \frac{-11}{26} + \frac {75}{26}i $$

Then, in order to find the modulus, I computed
$$|z| =\sqrt{x\cdot x + y\cdot y}$$

where $x = -11/26$ and $y = 75/26 $. Then,
$$|z| = \sqrt{\frac{-121}{676} + \frac {5625}{676}} = \sqrt{\frac{5746}{676}}$$

---

This is where I stopped.

How do I find the argument of $z$ from here?

Comment: Please show your work. I've used up all my close votes today, though.

Comment: What have you tried so far @Mr. Royal?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: **Hint:** Take each fraction, and multiply its numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the latter. This will lend itself to some nice simplifications and after some algebra I imagine you'll obtain something in the $a+bi$ form, for which we can much more easily find the modulus and the argument.

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I touched on in the comments, we begin by "rationalizing the denominator" in a sense, in that we multiply each fraction's top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator. Thus,

$$\frac{3+4i}{1-i} + \frac{2-i}{2+3i} = \frac{3+4i}{1-i} \left( \frac{1+i}{1+i} \right) + \frac{2-i}{2+3i} \left( \frac{2-3i}{2-3i} \right) \tag 1$$

The bottoms simplify nicely since $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2 - b^2$. Alternatively, since we have complex numbers, $z \bar z = |z|^2$; whichever you prefer to use.

Anyhow, $(1)$ becomes, with simplification,

$$\frac{3+4i}{1-i} \left( \frac{1+i}{1+i} \right) + \frac{2-i}{2+3i} \left( \frac{2-3i}{2-3i} \right) = \frac{-1+7i}{2} + \frac{1-8i}{13} \tag 2$$

We combine the real and imaginary parts to get

$$-\frac{11}{26} + \frac{75}{26}i$$

---

Up to this point, you've done everything correctly.

---

The number is a little messy but it can be worked with. Let $a = -11/26, b = 75/26$. Then the above number is $a+bi$. We know that for numbers in this form that

$$|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \;\;\;\;\;\; \arg(a+bi) = atan2(b,a)$$

Both of these are fairly evident if you imagine plotting $a+bi$ on the plane. Then its magnitude is the distance from the origin, which you can easily find from the Pythagorean theorem, and its argument is the angle it makes with the positive real axis (with counterclockwise rotation being positive). [The $atan2$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) can calculate this directly if you like, but the more "intuitive" definition (angle from the positive real axis) may be easier to contend with for you, all depending - you don't want to memorize that complex formula after all. You will have to use a little trig, regardless.

A rough image for a generic $z$ in the complex plane, to help further what I mean by these intuitive notions:

[image]

In any event, substitute $a,b$ into the expressions above and do the arithmetic to find the magnitude and argument.

If it were *me* finding the argument, I'd note that, since $a<0,b>0$, then $z=a+bi$ is in the top-left quadrant of the complex plane. Then I would find the angle $z$ makes with the *imaginary* axis and add $\pi/2$ radians to it. This diagram makes it clear why:

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect, the argument is not $\arctan$ (which by definition maps to only $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$)

Comment: My bad, I'll fix it

Comment: Instead of what you have written in your fix, the correct way of dealing with the situation is to compute $\pi+\arctan b/a$.

Comment: Which is handled precisely in the definition of $atan2$.

Comment: Dear @EeveeTrainer, there are a lot of things that are handled automatically in this  world. On another note, this formula is  not complex if one has a clear understanding of what is being computed.

Comment: It's complex in the sense that it's a lot to memorize outright. Simple to understand if you get the underlying geometric intuition, yes. But it's not something you generally want to memorize outright; so easy to misremember something, or mix up cases. Which is why I offer the point of view of geometry instead of just leaving it at that definition.

Answer (score 1):

in your solution, you find, correctly, $a$ and $b$ such that $\frac{3+4i}{1-i} + \frac{2-i}{2+3i} = a+bi$

but you need to find the modulus and the argument of the number. That is, you need to find $r>0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ such that

$$\frac{3+4i}{1-i} + \frac{2-i}{2+3i} = r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta).$$

There is a simple way to converting between the standard $a+bi$ format and the latter polar format.